# For fixed $A$ and $B$ find $C$ and $D$ that $|\frac{A}{B}-\frac{C}{D}|$ is minimal

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, fractions

We have $A$ and $B$.

$A/B$ - irreducible fraction.

You must find two natural numbers $C$ and $D$ that $|\frac{A}{B}-\frac{C}{D}|$ is minimal and $C/D$ - irreducible fraction. If there are multiple answers find $C$ and $D$ with the minimal $D$.

$0 < C < D < B$

$0 < A < B$

B > 2

$A$, $B$ - natural numbers.

Comment: Okay, I've done it.  Now what?

Comment: could you give me solution?

Comment: $C=A$ and $D=B$. Then the expression is $0$. Since it's absolute value, it cannot be less

Comment: @Andrei That doesn't match the constraint $D<B$

Comment: The continued fraction for $A/B$ could be helpful here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\gcd(A,B)=1$ to find $U,V\in\Bbb Z$ such that $UA+VB=1$.

*Remark:* The constraints sometimes prevent the existence of a solution. For example, $A=1$, $B=2$ satisfies $0<A<B$, but you cannot satisfy $0<C<D<B$. But there are also other strange cases where the hint above first produces a solution with $B\ge D$.

Comment: Okay, I found U and V. What next?